# RegEx for a delimited string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string like this `'432342:username:full_name:1'`. I need to write regular expression to check if string matches it.
I tried to .split(':') and then by accesing dict[i] checking if value in regular expression. But I need to match whole string.

**only numbers:english letters and numbers:english, russian letters:1,2,3**

> Also tried like this but I don't understand how to add ':' separator to separate the string. Like in example above

```
pattern = r'[/b:]|[\d]|[a-zA-Z]|[а-яА-Я]|[1,2,3]'
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate * any* effort at writing this regular expression yourself?

Comment: I tried to do it in dummy way. Check if there is len == 3 for pattern r'[:]'
then I splitting a string with ':' and accessing each element in dictionary and checking if string matches or not.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your instructions, try this:

```
s = '432342:username:full_name:1'
re.findall(r'[0-9]+:[a-zA-Z]+:[а-яА-Я_]+:[123]',s)
#['432342:username:full_name:1']
```